# How do i create a bootable usb to windows?

Tags: boot, windows, iso

Every time I try to make a bootable USB to windows I tried using startup disk creator and power iso and both haven't worked. I have a 16gb usb Ive formated it over at lease 20 times now trying and it doesn't work. I have flashed drive before and this time on linux is the most frustrating one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: Officially, the only way to do this is with Windows' media creation tool and it only works on Windows. It's closed source proprietary software

Comment: Old information is useless. It used to be that you could just extract the Windows ISO to a FAT32 formatted flash drive with esp,boot flags & have it boot in UEFI mode. But Microsoft has made the .wim file over 4GB, so it does not fit on a FAT32 formatted partition. The Windows tools split the .wim file to make it work. Most Linux tools do not even know about splitting a .wim file.

Comment: You can do it with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Answer (score 2):

### Windows Bootable USB using Ubuntu

There are many ways to make a Windows installer using Ubuntu.

**mkusb-plug** is my favorite, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274975/43926. I have also had good luck using mkusb-guidus to make Windows installers.

**Ventoy** for Linux can be used to boot Windows installer, see: https://www.ventoy.net/en/isolist.html. https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_linux_webui.html. Unfortunately Ventoy only created UEFI bootable Windows USB drives for me.

**Ubuntu** Windows can also be installed from Ubuntu without the need for a USB drive, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1337783/43926