Partition in ubuntu22
I would like to install dual-OS on my laptop. Currently my laptop only has Ubuntu22.04 installed, I want to partition some storage to install windows11.
However, I have googled a lot but only got results that you already have windows installed and partition some space to install Ubuntu.
So is there a safe way to parition some space particulary on Ubuntu22? Any link or videos are available for that?
Thank you for any advices!

This should help https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Partitioning is not the problem. Partitioning is easy. The problem is getting the Windows installer to respect existing partitions. That is a Windows support question, and should be directed to a Windows support venue.

New systems are now UEFI with gpt partitioning, not old MBR(msdos). Windows requires gpt for UEFI and requires MBR for BIOS boot. Many systems call UEFI as BIOS. But my Dell says BIOS, but once in "BIOS" it says UEFI only supported. Windows wants many partitions, so just make unallocated space.

Could you please update the question with your hardware specifications and the output of the lsblk command.

see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1337783/1698042

This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
